# Reducing the dimensionality of a vector

Tags: r, vector, dimension

How can I reduce the size of a vector to a lower dimension?

Say for example X:=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) is a 10-D vector. Suppose 
I want to reduce it to a 5 dimensional space. Is there any way to do this?

I have a situation where I need to compare an N-d vector with a corresponding vector of a lower dimension.

Comment: What would be the projection from 10D space to 5D space?

Comment: A simple Vector Say X:-(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) where X is to be transformed to Y where Y is a 5d vector.... Am kinda noob and I would like to know if this could be done ..

Comment: The wording of your question leads me to believe that you might not have a clear idea of what you wish to do. So you have a vector of length 10 and one of length 5 and you wish to compare them in some way. What kind of comparison do you wish to make? How are the vectors related?

Comment: You don't give enough information, but have you looked at factor analysis (?factanal) or principal component analysis (?princomp or ?prcomp)

Comment: Isn't that vector one-dimensional?

Answer (score 2):

There are an infinite number of ways to convert a 10d vector into a 5d vector.

This is like saying "I want a function that takes two integer parameters and returns an integer, can I make such a function".  There an infinite many such functions.

It really depends on what you want to do with the vector.  What are the meanings of your 10d and 5d vectors?

Comment: I need to find out the similarity between the 2 integer vectors.. and find out how similar those 2 vectors are by projecting them in the same n-d space....

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption is right, the OP would like to convert a vector of 10 values to a matrix with 2 columns.

This could be done easily in R:

```
# make up the demo data
> v <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

# modify the dimensions of 'v' to have 2 columns
> dim(v) <- c(5,2)

# and check the result
> v
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
```

Comment: @Pradeep: any feedback would be welcomed if my assumption was right or should I delete my answer. Thanks!